# SQL Server stored procedure : create increment ID in each occurrence of value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure and want to supplement the result a new column (`NameOcc`) that shows my value (`Name`) occurrence. This is a test table:

```
| Name |City| Day |
-------------------
| John | Oy |  1  |
| John | Oy |  7  |
|Peter | Oz |  3  |
| Boby | Pi |  9  |
| Boby | Pi |  4  |
| John | Pi |  4  |
| Boby | Pi |  8  |
```

I want this result:

```
| Name |City| Day |NameOcc|
---------------------------
| John | Oy |  1  |   1   |
| John | Oy |  7  |   2   |
|Peter | Oz |  3  |   1   |
| Boby | Pi |  9  |   1   |
| Boby | Pi |  4  |   2   |
| John | Pi |  5  |   3   |
| Boby | Pi |  8  |   3   |
```

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain how 1/2/3 have been assigned to the Boby rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE(common-table-expression) + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT n.*, 
           NameOcc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, City ORDER BY Name, City, Day)
    FROM dbo.Names n
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a3f9/3/0)

[**Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f42b0/2/0) is a more meaningful example with the correct order derived from a primary-key column that you haven't provided. The logic is the same.

Comment: Though ordering by day doesn't seem to give the exact results the OP lists in the question. Not sure if they don't care or if they expect the row numbers to be applied based on some fact we can't know (like another column) or possibly can't determine (such as order of insert).

Comment: And I've up-voted it, just seeking clarity from the OP and trying to provide it for other readers.

Comment: As I see it, this will only work well if the test field (Name) is ordered to the table. But my table is not ordered the Name field. <br/>[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6d15/1)

Comment: @cofeee: i don't see what's wrong. Change the `ORDER BY` to `Name, NameOcc` and you see the same names under each other. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96b42/2/0 You haven't even mentioned an order.

Comment: Look line 7 of Example. It is also John, but the "counter" (NameOcc) is 1. I'm waiting there 3.

Comment: @cofeee: that's because i have included the `City` in the group, so that not only the `Name` is taken into account but the combination of name and city. If that's not desired change it to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID)` as here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6d15/5/0

Comment: I'm sorry Tim, it was my fault. Everything works fine!